# Linear Independence in Finite Field

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is the list $(1, 1+z)$ where $z \in \operatorname{GF}(2)$ linearly independent over the finite field of order $2$?

I understand that a set of vectors is linearly independent if the only way to write $0$ as a linear combination of them is with all their coefficients equal to $0$, but for specific values of $z$ (namely $0$ and $1$) the list is not linearly independent. Particularly I am trying to find a basis for the set of polynomials of degree less than or equal to m with coefficients in GF(2) mapping GF(2) to GF(2).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  I think you're right:  either $1+z=0$, which is not linearly independent of anything, or $1+z=1$, which is not linearly independent of $1$

Comment: But if you're really interested in polynomials over the field, and not elements of the field, then $\{\,1,1+z\,\}$ is a linearly independent set, indeed, a basis for the vector space of polynomials of degree at most one over the field GF(2).